# dell inspiron 15r se 75 20 with win 10

Tags: keyboard

my laptop is dell inspiron 15r se 7520. i replaced my hard disk and re-installed the win10 . everything works fine except the keyboard: works only with small letters. when i move to caps - the whole keyboard is stacked and i have to restart my pc, nothing else releases it. i guess it is a matter of a driver?, maybe i need not the latest version of it? if so i don't know where to get it from because when i search the web i get a lot of answers, don't know which is the one. i already tried one and it didn't solve the problem. of course, before installation i removed the old one.

pazi.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. There are a few details missing from your question. Have you installed all the Windows updates since the fresh install? Did you check Dell's support site for model specific drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Usually keyboard doesn't require additional plugins to regular keys to work. did you examine your laptop for hardware defaults? (dust in keyboard, loose connections etc.. ?)
you can also use windows update and install latest version. also check Dell official web site with your laptop model for additional drivers

hope this helps